# Should we clean-up some "Catch-all" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are some tags- which becomes "catch-all" i.e. they are essentially redundant and can be applied anywhere or they don't quite have very direct classification meaning to the question.

Some of the list is as below:

1. [algorithms](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms)
2. [frequency](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frequency)
3. [reference-request](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)
4. [soft-question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question)
5. [random](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)  : may should be called random-numbers
6. [terminology](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)
7. [measurement](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement)
8. [source](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source)
9. [timing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timing)
10. [phase](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phase) : its a correct term -but a horrible name for tag.
11. [nomenclature](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature)

Should we cleanup some of these tags? and remove them permanently?

Comment: No response to this?

Comment: ah in fact, I've been doing that as I go along. When I see a post with a tag that I consider "strange"/catch-all, I simply look up the tag. If it's sub-5 questions, I look into whether they could be retagged better, and then just do that, making tags disappear. In fact, I've [made](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/can-we-get-rid-of-and-lock-the-signal-tag#comment698_1442) [tag:signal] and [tag:processing] disappear (I hope), since they carry zero entropy.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning tags or giving them some distinct content is a good idea. However, I have the feeling that `algorithms`, `reference-request`, `measurement` are useful to me, unless you propose a replacement? I may have added those tags to first posts, or when editing.

I believe that tags should be considered by the relations, with respect to antonyms, dual, or complementary terms. For instance, `algorithms` makes sense to me with respect to `theory`.

But I am surprised by `addition`, seldom used (and potentially catch-all), while `additive` refers to a much more interesting property of signals and systems