# Can we get rid of and lock the [signal] tag?

Tags: discussion

On a "Signal Processing" site, adding a [signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal) tag to a question actually carries absolutely no information.

Worse, even, is that most of the questions tagged with it are of mediocre-to-bad quality¹ (not surprising, since it shows the poster didn't take a step back to consider what tags would concisely describe his/her question) and that people seem to type things "audio signal" into the tag field and end up with [audio](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio)[signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal).

Since the existence of this tag alone allows people to just post questions without finding a better tag to use, I think the appropriate measure would be to not only remove the tag (manually, probably) from the 160-something questions that carry it right now, but also to blacklist it from being created again.

Hence the question: Should we do that? Does the esteemed moderatorship agree?

---

¹ from the 155 [non-closed, non-migrated, non-duplicate questions](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsignal%5D+closed%3Ano+duplicate%3Ano+migrated%3Ano+is%3Aquestion) tagged with [signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal) at the point of writing, we get this score histogram:

[image: fancy barplot with the sole purpose of proving my point :)]

which hopefully is a lot worse than the average tag's score histogram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree.  I'm digging into how to delete tags; the only way seems to be to [remove the offending tag from all questions and then wait.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags)

Funnily enough, the <kbd>processing</kbd> is also there, though with only about 70 tagged posts.

There is other great advice [here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/131640)

Comment: As hinted at, there should be a blacklisting capability that inhibits adding the tag to new questions completely; without that, removing the tag from all questions is but a temporary solution.

Comment: At least that's how it's over at StackOverflow. See the case of the [godaddy] tag on meta.SO.

Comment: Began to work on the manual un-tagging. Started with the zero-score questions – sorry to spam everyone's close vote queue! I've been applying close votes liberally; many of those questions had comments asking for clarification that never received a reaction, and thus, "unclear" is a common close vote reason this afternoon.

Comment: bringing your attention to this again: I'm again in the process of de-tagging questions. There have been several questions tagged with [tag:signal] since we 2016-11-11; have you been able to figure something out regarding blacklisting?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ya it needs the tag to be burninated, which mods can't do. Developers need to be involved. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag

Comment: I'm traveling at the moment (and my flight yesterday was cancelled :( ), so I won't be much use until tomorrow. I started helping with removing the tag, but too many seemed to be popping up again.

Comment: Don't get all worried! It was really just a *ping* :) I'll do some cleaning up!

Comment: **Done**! I'm going to celebrate this by having lunch.

Comment: **Done**! With both [tag:signal] and [tag:processing].

Comment: Please approve my [tag:processing] tag excerpt edit.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: This type of bad tag is called an intrinsic tag and there is a feature specifically to blacklist that kind of tag. It can be found in the moderator links as [“Blacklisted User Input”](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/admin/blacklist). (I can't actually view that link, not myself being a moderator here, but I guess it will turn out to contain “dsp” but not “signal”.)

Moderators may [ask for tags to be added to this blacklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218532/159388) but cannot do it themselves.

Comment: Thanks! yep, that's what is what I was hoping we'll find out.