# What are the "intrinsic tags" tags we'd want to block?

Tags: discussion, tags

Following the question

> [Can we get rid of and lock the [signal] tag?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1441/13320)

and especially Kevin's [answer](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1450/13320)

> FYI: This type of bad tag is called an intrinsic tag and there is a feature specifically to blacklist that kind of tag. It can be found in the moderator links as “Blacklisted User Input”.

**We might want to compile a list of tags that carry no information**, when posted on signals./dsp.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 2):

So far, we'd have:

- [signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal)
- [processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/processing)
- [signal-processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-processing) (which probably is already blacklisted)
- [dsp](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dsp) (which probably is already blacklisted)

We might want to:

- replace ~-processing with just "~"

  - image-
  - audio-
  - video-

Comment: I would add [tag:dsp-core]. It seems to be mostly misused, as I guess people interpret it as "core DSP knowledge" instead of a "DSP processing core."

Comment: @JasonR hm, I considered that to be an important tag; it's what people use to tag things that actually have to do with digital signal *processors* (be it some motoroloa 56k or some TI C6000)

Comment: I agree, that's what the tag is for. My point is that if you look at the questions that use it, it's almost always misused to mean "core DSP knowledge" instead of "DSP processing core."

Comment: I see. Haven't had a look, yet, though. So, any better idea? "digital signal processor" will probably have the same problem, just worse. "dsp-ic" might work.

Comment: by the way, this is a wiki answer. Edit it, add a section "under discussion" and add dsp-core with an explanation there.