# Notice: I've just removed all [tag:audio-processing] tags; blacklist?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Since [audio](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) was used with but two of the 12 questions, that tag seems very redundant.

I'd recommend a [*tag blacklist*](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1450/13320) for that, just to avoid it being added later on. It's an intrinsic tag.

related: https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1452/13320 "What are the intrinsic tags we'd want to get rid of".

Answer (score 3):

you're probably right in regard to this forum.  if it was more of a hardcore audio DSP forum, i might think that [audio-processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-processing), [audio-analysis](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-analysis), and [audio-synthesis](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-synthesis) are three different functions.

but put it all under [audio](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio), i think that's good enough and i wouldn't wanna see any tag inflation happening here.

Comment: Agree; On the other hand, I'd rather see a diversification than a conflation of different things. I'd agree: synthesis is not the same as analysis, and processing is a different category of term, and all three are useful on their own.